# No duplicate characters in string output - Python

Tags: python, string, random, duplicates

#### What im making

**Hi!**
Im making a password generator script in Python ( Script below ). and i was wondering what the best way would be to make sure the passwords dont have two of the same character/symbol right after eachother.

as an example:

```
kjhd8!3JJp-#huwwg
```

i would like a way within my script to make sure the duplicates arent "touching". if that makes sense (my english isnt very good).

the same password can have the same character, thats fine. but i would like it not to have them "touching"

like:

```
kjwhd8!3Jp-#huwJg
```

if that makes sense.

---

### The script

```py
import random
import string
import sys

#amount of passwords to make
amount = 10

# Characters and symbols to use for the password
# ive split it up to make sure it takes from all of the lists
chars ="abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJK"
specials="#####!-----"
digits="2346789"
characters = list(chars + digits + specials)

def generate_random_password():
    # length of the passwords
    length = 18

    # mixes and shuffles the characters
    random.shuffle(characters)

    # Puts the sections together at random
    password = []
    for i in range(length):
        password.append(random.choice(characters) )

    # another shuffle to make sure (probably noy needed but meh)
    random.shuffle(password)

    # converts to a string
    print("".join(password))

# Prints out as many passswords as stated in the "amount" variable
for index in range(amount):
    generate_random_password()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check if the generated char is the same that the previous one, if it is: pick another char, else continue.

```py
prev_char=None
for i in range(length):
        random_char = random.choice(characters)
        while prev_char == random_char:
                random_char = random.choice(characters)
        password.append(random_char)
        prev_char = random_char
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for this!

### The expression:

```
(.)\1
```

### What it does:

```
(.)   - group that matches one character
\1    - reference to group 1 (the group above)
```

What this essentially does is that it looks for a character repeating right after itself.

### How to use it?

```
import re

any(re.findall(r"(.)\1", "kjwhd8!3Jp-#huwJg"))
```

`findall` will find any ocurrences of this; `any` will give you `True` or `False` if there are any cases.

Note: You could also extend this so that the same character doesn't repeat within the next let's say 4 characters: `(.).{0,4}\1`

Comment: this looks very cool! but im not totally sure about where in the script im supposed to impliment this? should i use this in the first or last for loop in my script?